# Importing VC++ DLL into C# code

Tags: c#, visual-c++, opencv, dllimport

I am building a C# application. I imported a VC++ DLL which uses openCV for image comparsion.
The prototype of the function I need to access in openCV is
bool DGTestAutomation_ImgCmp(IplImage* img1, IplImage* img2, int normalization_val, int tolerance);

The images in C# are stored as bitmaps
How do I pass these bitmaps into the DLL?
The current code I am using is

```
public class DLL
{
    [DllImport("DGTestAutomation_DLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool DGTestAutomation_ImgCmp(
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IPLImage)]Bitmap bmp1,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IPLImage)]Bitmap bmp2, 
         int normalization_val, int tolerance);
}
```

Calling the DLL

```
bool check = DLL.DGTestAutomation_ImgCmp(bmp1, bmp2, 0, 9);
```

Error

> 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType'

I have just started learning the DLL stuff. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: For rather complicated APIs, it might be easier to write a C++/CLI wrapper for your pure C++ library. That way you have a project in which both types (.NET and C++) are valid and you can convert between them without having all the "evil" pointer arithmetics and handle casting in C#.

Comment: I thought I could avoid creating a wrapper but the pointer arithmetic seem more "evil" than I anticipated them to be. I am looking if there is any way to avoid creating a wrapper. Looks like that's a better solution though. Thanks

Comment: You might want to consider using OpenCV functionality via [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV), which is a .NET wrapper over OpenCV.